# Convert date from access to SQL Server with SSIS

Tags: ms-access, date, ssis

I want to convert a database from access to SQL Server using SSIS. I cannot convert the date/time columns of the access db. SSIS says something like:

```
conversion between DT_Date and DT_DBTIMESTAMP is not supported.
```

(Its translated from my German version, might be different in English version). In Access I have Date/Time column, in SQL Server I have datetime. In the dataflow chart of the SSIS I have a OLE DB source for the access db, an sql server target and a data conversion. In the data conversion I convert the columns to date[DT_DATE]. They are connected like this:

```
AccessDB -> conversion -> SQL DB
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I convert the Access date columns to SQL Server date columns?

Comment: The error icon occurs in the sql sever target

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need to add a specific conversion to convert this column to the correct type.  It's the DT_DBTIMESTAMP that you need to convert to, not DT_DATE.  Using a Derived Column Transformation for instance, you could use an expression like:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)YourDateColumn
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I add a derived column tranformation and I cast the column to DT_DBTIMESTAMP I get the error that the conversion from DT_DATE to DT_DBTIMESTAMP is not supported.

Comment: That's weird. I tried it out by downloading the old Northwind Access DB sample from 1999, converting it to Access 2003, then creating an SSIS package with an OLE DB Source connecting to that Access MDB, retrieving the Orders table (which contains several DT_DATE - or in Access known as date/time - columns), attaching a Derived Column Transform to the OLEDB source, and I could cast to DT_DBDATETIME without any problems.

Are you sure that the previous conversion is not causing this error (was it removed)?

Comment: Yes, I removed the previous conversion. Now I have "AccessDB -> Derived Column Transformation -> SQL DB". But the error is shown in the last Box, the SQL DB. Could this be the problem? I created a new table in the db with SSIS using the standard SQL that is created when you click on the new button in the properties of the SQL DB. Which data types did you use for the target DB?

Comment: Here's the statement as it was generated in my case:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AccessImportTest](
    [OrderID] [int] NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NULL,
    [OrderDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RequiredDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ShippedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ShipVia] [int] NULL,
    [ShipAddress] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [Derived Column 1] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

(removed some unrelated fields to make it fit in a comment)

That last field is the one added by the Derived Column Transform, so a DT_DBTIMESTAMP. The other 3 datetime fields are DT_DATE in the flow (ctd next comment).

Comment: Funny enough, I didn't have any issue inserting the DT_DATE columns in a datetime field in the SQL DB.

This is my data flow: OLE DB Source (connecting to Access) > Derived Column Transformation > OLE DB Destination (connecting to SQL2008)

Just to be complete, these are the full names of the providers in the connection managers:
Source: Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider
Destination: SQL Server Native Client 10.0

Comment: If that doesn't help: have you got SP1 installed on your client?

Answer (score 0):

You use another Provider on the source side. I used the JET provider. I am doing this on a computer where no Access is installed. When I try to create a data connection using the Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider I get an error message that the workgroup information file is missing. I get this message on the connection test.

The question is if the conversion depends on the db driver you use to get the data. I cannot install Access on the server I am working, so I cannot try it. Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: oops, I cannot answer your comment any more ...

I have version 10.0.1600.22 and the SP1 version on the MS site says 10.00.2531.00, so I guess I dont have it.

Comment: I recommend that you install SP1 first before trying anything else. It doesn't make any sense to search for a solution when the problem is possibly caused by a bug that has already been solved many months ago...

Furthermore, the ACE driver (the newer version of JET, which is what I used in my test) is available as a free download: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891&displaylang=en

There's also a version for Office 2010, and it should be backward-compatible.  I suggest to give that a try if you can.  Should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Casting **D_Date** column to **DT_DBTIMESTAMP** solve the same problem for me.